# Change color of input field after the submit has failed

Tags: html, css, input, colors, submit

I would like to know if there is a way to change the color of an input field after you clicked on a submit button, like change it's color to red if the input is invalid. My current solution marks every input red at the beginning, because of my current css code.

```
input:invalid {  
  background: #FF3300;  
}
```

I want the input fields to remain white until you hit submit button, then the correct inputs should turn green while the incorrect ones should turn red.
Thanks in advance.

Small example.
HTML:

```
<html><!DOCTYPE html>
    <head>
      <title>Example</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="javascript.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
         <form action="">
            <input type="text" id="name" class="input"  maxlength="50"  pattern="[A-Za-z\\s]*" placeholder="Name" required>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="Submit">
        </form>
    </body> 
</html>
```

CSS:

```
input:invalid {
  background: #FF3300;
}

input:valid {
  background: lightgreen;
}
#Submit{
    background: lightgrey;
}
```

Comment: You will need any JavaScript logic in your form. This library for jquery may help you [Click](http://jqueryvalidation.org/)

Comment: I haven't worked with jquery yet, so I would have to look into that before using any libraries. Is there any other way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
   <html>
       <head>
           <title>Say I'm a duck</title>
       </head>
       <body>
            <script>
               function verify(){
                   var value = document.forms[0].item.value; // or replace document.forms[0].item by document.getElementById('name')
                   var objective = "I'm a duck";
                   if(objective != value){
                       document.forms[0].item.style.color="#FF3300";
                       return false;
                   } else {
                       document.forms[0].item.style.color="lightgreen";
                   }
                   return true;
               }
           </script>
           <form action="" method="" onSubmit="verify();">
               <input type="text" name="item" id="name" class="input"  maxlength="50"  pattern="[A-Za-z\\s]*" placeholder="Name" required>
           <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="Submit">
           </form>
       </body>
   </html>
```

The onSubmit property will call the js verif() function.

In javascript, the call to *DOM Object*.style.*property* = *value*; will change the object style.

[W3School js change css](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_css.asp)

Admin XVII

Answer (score 0):

You may have incorrectly set parameters in the tag input. That is: type, required, pattern. Read more on the Internet about HTML5 form validation. CSS selector you are correct. Please note that this method works only in modern browsers supporting HTML5, in older browsers, you will have to use JS libraries to validate the form or write a small script in PHP.

Comment: I used all of those tags. I added a small example if you want to try it out.

Comment: Try `pattern="[a-zA-Z]+"` and css `.input:invalid { border: 2px solid red; }`

Comment: Didn't really fix the problem, at least it looks more pleasing now.

Comment: @PeterFlash this is work perfectly for your case, as I understand. CSS before any key pressed draws black border. After any key pressed in form, small JS on input tag remove dummy attribute and CSS start validate through :valid\:invalid selector. html: `<input type="text" def="null" id="name" maxlength="50" pattern="[a-zA-Z]+" onkeydown="this.removeAttribute('def');" required>` css:`#name:invalid {border: 2px solid red;}
#name[def='null'] {border: 1px solid black;}
#name:valid {border: 2px solid lightgreen;}`(use in that order). If I helped you please press the response is useful and accepted.

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking for is one of angularJS features.

But to answer your question... First of all I asume you are using ajax, or the reload won't show the input any more. If that is so, when you get an error from the call you can add an `.invalid` class, so instead you'd need this:

```
input.invalid {  
  background: #FF3300;  
}
```

And on ajax error:

```
document.querySelector(".targetInput").classList.add("invalid");
```

Comment: I'm not using ajax, this is just a small sample to get familiar with HTML. I never used it before. Everything disappears on reload, but it's intended to work like that.

Comment: Then asume that the error is thrown by the validator tool. It will work The same way

Answer (score -1):

Have you considered using JQuery validation plugin?

```
$("form").validate({
    errorClass: "my-error-class",
    validClass: "my-valid-class",
    rules: {
            test: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 12
            }
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8vQFd/